# Can a name be used as an adjective, as in "this Smithers issue?"

Tags: grammar

Example:

> Because of this Mrs. Johnson matter, I hadn’t had much time to think
>   about De-Shi and me.

The part I'm concerned about is "because of this Mrs. Johnson matter..." Can a name be used as an adjective?

Is this grammatical? If not, what's the correct alternative?

Comment: No full stop needed after a person's title, Mr Chenco.

Comment: @JoeDark [Does "Mr" take a period?](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/does-mr-take-a-period/) "*Whether or not to place a period after Mr. and Mrs. depends upon whether you are following American or British usage.*" American English uses periods after shortened titles, but British English does not use periods (if the shortened title ends with the same letter as the full title -- in BrE, `Mr` does not, but `Prof.` does). Also: [Full Stops (Periods) in Contractions](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/abbreviations_contractions_full_stops_periods.htm).

Comment: @apsillers A pox on your colonial aberrant vulgarisms sir!

Answer (score 5):

This usage is correct. The construct is called a "[noun modifier](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/noun-modifiers)" (a noun that *modifies* another noun).

The phrase "this Mrs. Johnson matter" would be clearly understood by an English speaker as "this matter that is related to Mrs. Johnson".

Here are some similar uses of modifier nouns:

> Our building has a **rat problem**. (*a problem with rats*)
>
> The police are still trying to solve the **Smith murder**. (*the murder of Mr. Smith*)
>
> Due to lack of rain, our city has a **water shortage**. (*a shortage of water*)

Comment: alex: I'll bet you've heard dozens of these before, but you just hadn't bothered to parse the sentence or think that much about the parts of speech. In addition to the fine examples here, there's also a _Hitchcock twist,_ a _measles outbreak_, a _Christie novel_, and (my favorite here on ELL) a _StoneyB answer_.